# Java. БД. Консольный ввод-вывод

Tags: java, база-данных

Всем привет.

Есть следующая задача:

> Реализовать консольный ввод-вывод имени и фамилии используя БД (программа позволяет ввести ФИО, сохранить ФИО, вывести список всех данных из БД).

Я еще ни разу не сталкивалась с работой с БД. С чего начать вообще? Так-то я могу просто записывать все в какой-нибудь `ArrayList` и сортировать по алфавиту, но подозреваю, что это как-то по-другому должно выглядеть.

Comment: Начните с SQL, например и нормальных форм.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов с pl/sql нет проблем с синтаксисом никаких. Но все равно не знаю как в java это организовать. Нормальные формы не трогала - ERwin сам все под 3нф подгонял-этого хватало. Вопрос о том, как это должно выглядеть вообще? Вот ввожу я с консольки ФИО и куда оно сохраняется, если не в массив?

Comment: Значит, наверное, вам нужно изучить Java. А потом изучить работу Java с конкретной СУБД...

Comment: Для начала ставим локально какую-нибудь SQL/NoSQL-базу. Создаём таблицу в базе типа `CREATE TABLE persons ( surname    TEXT,  name  TEXT, patronymic TEXT );`. Находим подходящий `JDBC` драйвер, прикручиваем его в проект и соответственно пишем через него, читаем и т.д.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Данная задача решается с помощью `JDBC`.

1.Создай локальную БД.
К примеру,

```
CREATE TABLE USERS (user_name text)
```

2.Подключи к проекту соответствующей БД `JDBC-драйвер`.

3.Создай метод или класс обращения к `JDBC`. К примеру такой:

```
Connection connection = null;
Statement statement = null;
ResultSet result = null;

String url = "CONNECTION_URL"; // url конекшена JDBC
String login = "LOGIN"; // логин БД
String password = "PASSWORD"; // пароль БД

try {
    Class.forName("org.mysql.Driver"); // путь к драйверу
    connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, login, password);
    statement = connection.createStatement();
    result = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM USERS");
    while(result.next()) {
         System.out.println(result.getString("user_name")); // считываем имя пользователя, полученной записи
    }
} catch(ClassNotFoundException | SQLException exc) { }
finally {
    try {
        if(connection!=null) connection.close();
        if(statement!=null) statement.close();
        if(result!=null) result.close();
    } catch (SQLException exc) {}
}
```

Cоветую ознакомиться с [документацией Оракла](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/), там все довольно понятно объяснено и много примеров.

Ну, а также еще советую этот [источник](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/index.htm).